# Appendix: Remove letter from chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, appendices

I have a document with a single appendix chapter. Latex is numbering this as "Appendix-Chapter A". But because it is my only appendx chapter, I want only to show "Appendix-Chapter".

Current source:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\appendix
\chapter{Algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Results in:

```
Contents
 1. Test      3
 A. Algorithm 5

Chapter 1.
Test

Appendix A.
Algorithm
```

Wished result

```
Contents    
 1. Test     3    
 Algorithm   5

Chapter 1
Test

Appendix
Algorithm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use

```
\addchap{Algorithm}
```

instead of

```
\chapter{Algorithm}
```

In this way, you have an unnumbered chapter with a ToC entry. However, it does not exactly what you want.

If you want to obtain this, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\appendix{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    {\chapapp\autodot\enskip}%
  }
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
    {\chapapp\autodot\enskip}%
  }
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}%
    {\addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
    {\addchaptertocentry{}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
    {}
    {}
}
\makeatother
```

MWE (I've added the option `numbers=noenddot` since it seems that you want to use it):

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\appendix{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    {\chapapp\autodot\enskip}%
  }
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
    {\chapapp\autodot\enskip}%
  }
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}%
    {\addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
    {\addchaptertocentry{}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
    {}
    {}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\appendix
\chapter{Algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

Output (Appendix):

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you are using `hyperref` this is the stuff to be added in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\appendix{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    {\chapapp\autodot\enskip}%
  }
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
    {\chapapp\autodot\enskip}%
  }
  \patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}%
    {\addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
    {\addchaptertocentry{}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
    {}
    {}
}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\appendix{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    {\chapapp\autodot\enskip}%
  }
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
    {\chapapp\autodot\enskip}%
  }
  \patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}%
    {\addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
    {\addchaptertocentry{}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
    {}
    {}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\appendix
\chapter{Algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

Comment: This solution don't work in combination with hyperref :(

Comment: @SunBlack See the edit.